# AWS Glue crawler reading GZIP header info

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, header, gzip, aws-glue

I have set up a crawler in Glue, which crawls compressed CSV files (GZIP format) from S3 bucket. I have an ETL job which converts this CSV into Parquet and another crawler which read parquet file and populates parquet table.

The first crawler which reads compressed CSV file (GZIP format) seems like reading GZIP file header information. CSV file has five fields. Below is the sample data

**3456789,1,200,20190118,9040**

However after crawler populates the table, row looks like below.

**xyz.csv0000644000175200017530113404730513420142427014701 0ustar wlsadmin3456789 1** 200 20190118 9040

First column has some additional data which has file name and the user name of the machine where the GZIP file created.

Any idea, how can I avoid this situation and read correct values.

Comment: share sample gzip file

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you will not able to create the table by using AWS Glue Crawler in your case.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html

Of course you can try to implement Glue Grok Custom Classifier, but it can be dificult to do.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-grok

I suggest to create the table manually, by using Create command in Athena or in Glue console. Because you need to skip first row you have to set 'skip.header.line.count'='1' option in TBLPROPERTIES. The definition of this table may look as the following example:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `gzip_test`(
  `col1` bigint, 
  `col2` bigint, 
  `col3` bigint, 
  `col4` bigint, 
  `col5` bigint)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://example/example'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='csv', 
  'columnsOrdered'='true', 
  'compressionType'='gzip', 
  'delimiter'=',', 
  'skip.header.line.count'='1', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Comment: I don't want to skip the first row. CSV files we processing don't have header info in it. Probably I should say, file properties such as filename, author etc are appended along with the first row. First row is actually include valid data. Hence I can't skip it. I think Crawler is appending GZIP file properties to the first row. So, I want to get rid of that

Comment: You can remove this line "  'skip.header.line.count'='1', " from presented table definition and it should work. Glue Crawler doesn't add any information to the data, it can only misinterpreted the file(s). Could you send your table definition generated by Clawler? (SHOW CREATE TABLE example;)